# How could I silently ignore objects not being decoded in a list using Swift 4's Codable protocol?

Tags: swift, swift4, codable

Is there a way to decode a JSON that is a list of objects when some of these objects can't be decoded properly? Let's say I have a `enum` with 2 possible values `foo` and `bar` but all of sudden backend starts to return another possible option for that field (let's say `other`).

Looking to the example below, first part is fine. What I wanted is to have in the second part, a list containing 1 element (`foo`), instead of `nil`.

```
import Foundation

enum Value: String, Codable {
    case foo
    case bar
}

struct Object: Codable {
    let value: Value
}

let dataList = "[{\"value\":\"foo\"}, {\"value\":\"bar\"}]".data(using: .utf8)!
let objectList = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Object].self, from: dataList) // [{foo}, {bar}]

let anotherDataList = "[{\"value\":\"foo\"}, {\"value\":\"other\"}]".data(using: .utf8)!
let anotherObjectList = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Object].self, from: anotherDataList) // nil

// is there a way to have this ^ as [{foo}] instead of nil?
```

Comment: Here's a solution from a duplicate thread, for anyone who comes across this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46369152/4039079